# My Desktop wallpaper appears for a few seconds after startup then disappears!

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, xorg

- I have installed Ubuntu `20.04` and I have noticed that using NVIDIA driver makes my machine gets pretty hot, so I changed the driver to XORG open source.
- after doing that I have got a wired behavior:

[image]

I tried to change the aspect ratio, but there was no progress, can you please recommend me a solution? without removing NVIDIA drivers because I use them for deep learning, thanks in advance.

### EDIT: I rolled back to NVIDIA driver the problem still, and here is a [video of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQKBbiT42odo7nM9N1p8546g-M22VlJK/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered some similar issues as well, recently.

You could try :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Then reboot. If it doesn't work, try :

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg
```

Hopefully it will solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried that, but the background is completely black, I can't see my wallpaper anymore!

Comment: Ok, maybe last try but here what I did the last time : 
`sudo apt-get remove xorg`
`apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-nvidia`
`apt install xserver -xorg`
`update-initramfs -u -k all`